# Program in x64 assembly modifying array passed from a C++ procedure in Linux does not work, though analogous solution worked for x86

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm, x86-64, low-level

I wrote a program in x64 assembly to replace a string's lower-case letters with stars. The assembly procedure is called from a C++ program and receives an array of chars. The similar logic applied for x86 worked (the difference being registers used etc.), but now the string remains unaltered when built for x64. I use Debian Linux and `nasm`.

```
section .text
global  func

func:
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

; zadanie jako takie
    mov rax, QWORD [rbp+8]
    loop:
        cmp BYTE [rax], 97
        jl increment
        cmp BYTE [rax], 122
        jg increment
        mov BYTE [rax], 42
        increment:
        add rax, 1
        cmp BYTE [rax], 0
        jne loop


    exit:
    mov rax, 0          ;return 0
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

It is called from the following C++ program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LENGTH 1024

extern "C" int func(char *a);

int main(void)
{
  int result;

  char text[LENGTH];
  printf( "Write some string\n" );
  fgets( text, LENGTH -1, stdin );


  printf("String: %s\n", text);
  result=func(text);
  printf("String: %s\n", text);

  return 0;
}
```

If necessary, here's the `makefile`:

```
CC=gcc
ASMBIN=nasm

all : asm cc link
asm : 
    $(ASMBIN) -o func.o -f elf64 -l func.lst func.asm
cc :
    $(CC) -m64 -c -g -O0 main.cc
link :
    $(CC) -m64 -o test -lstdc++ main.o func.o
clean :
    rm *.o
    rm test
    rm errors.txt   
    rm func.lst
```

Additionally, any resources for porting from x86 to x64 would be appreciated.

Comment: Side note: You aren't handling empty strings correctly. You should check for `0` *before* incrementing.

Comment: x86-64 uses different calling convention. Read the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) article or the abi docs.

Comment: @Jester so what's precisely wrong? Somehow I cannot extract it from wiki.

Comment: @Jester ok, I got it now, thanks for the hint. What are abi docs btw?

Comment: @ikegami your unnecessary question editing changed its meaning. I did not compile the exact same code for both x86 and x64. I said code with the same logic worked for x86 and this one obviously wouldn't, which you would know if you analyzed the code. I was referring to the logic of instructions, the algorithm itself, that worked, in order to stress that the problem lies in differences between assemblies themselves. And with those differences I was asking for help.

Comment: What you said what also wrong. It's not the algorithm that's malfunctioning. And even though the algorithm sucks, I'm sure that's not what you're interested in fixing. (You fixed it an hour ago; why are you complaining now?)

Comment: @ikegami it wasn't as far as meaning is concerned. I just restored the original one. I wanted to make you more cautious when you do the editing. My English may be not perfect, but I think it is more important to stay on topic than to be pedantic about the English language quality.

Comment: Huh? You didn't restore anything. What's there's now is completely different than what you had originally. My fix was better than the original. Your fix is even better.

Comment: Re "it is really silly to focus on the algorithm in such a trivial problem." I know. You're the one who said it was a problem with the algorithm. Twice.  I said it wasn't. I changed the question to remove that bit. I put it on topic when it was off-topic. I did exactly what you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the program does not work is the different calling convention in x64. See: [link](http://wiki.osdev.org/Calling_Conventions) for reference. The address of the string array wasn't passed on a stack, as it would be the case of x86, but stored in the rdi register. Therefore the solution is to change the instruction loading the array address into:

```
mov rax, rdi
```